# How do I resume/resend a request after getting a new refresh token using Angular JS with JWT Auth/ Laravel?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, jwt

Here's the case:
    On a successful login the client will get a token and I'm sending it with every request in the http header
    The user uses my app  for sometime and bit later when making a add to basket action the jwt token gets expired and I will be throwing an error like 40* something and will be issuing a new request to get the token.

My problem is that How do I resume the last failed request after getting the new token? I can write this manually on every error response part, but it takes a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular save the http text to the cookies or other store every time.Then
your Laravel return a error number such as 110.If your angular get this number 110 it will resume the http requests that last time.

Comment: what?? Please clarify.

Comment: When your client post/get a http requests you can save the request's content to the cookies.If  jwt token is expired your laravel response a error number.When the client get the number user need login then client read the cookie's request content and send it.